# How to combine records start date and end date in SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a set of data example below:

| ID | Role | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-03 |
| 1 | A | 2022-02-03 | 2022-02-10 |
| 1 | A | 2022-02-10 | 9000-12-31 |
| 2 | B | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-03 |
| 2 | A | 2022-02-03 | 2022-02-04 |
| 2 | B | 2022-02-04 | 2022-02-11 |

I want to group them based on the ID, ROLE, START_DATE and END_DATE. So it looks like below:
x

| ID | Role | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2022-02-01 | 9000-12-31 |
| 2 | B | 2022-02-01 | 2022-02-03 |
| 2 | A | 2022-02-03 | 2022-02-04 |
| 2 | B | 2022-02-04 | 2022-02-11 |

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Which database  you are using ? tag correct database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple task for Teradata's NORMALIZE:

```
with cte as
 ( -- works on PERIODs only
   select NORMALIZE -- combine overlapping periods
      ID, Role, period(START_DATE, END_DATE) as pd
   from mytable
 )
-- split period back into start/end
select ID, Role, begin(pd) as START_DATE, end(pd) as END_DATE
from cte
```

Comment: Perfect! Great to learn this function